# Ruby on Rails app 500 Internal Server error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can get the index.html and a test page to come up in the browser from the public folder, but the exact/path in the controller is not coming up.  The browser continues to search for the page until I stop it.  It works in my test environment and it works in Heroku, but doesn't not work on my amazon ec2 server.  I am using Ubuntu 11.10. Why would this be?  Thanks in advance.

Update:  It looks like I am getting a 500 Internal Server error and the controller is not seen.

Comment: Check the response headers for your HTTP requests to your app.  Are you getting back a 200?  Is it just taking a long time to process your page (long DB access times)?

Comment: for the test page I got 206 - Partial Content.  For the /exact/path I got When requesting the URL http://www.site-scan.com/cgi-bin/show_headers.pl from this server the following problem occurred: 500 - Internal Server Error

If this problem occurred while you followed a link from this website please contact the webmaster, informing him about the location of the link, the exact time the problem occurred and any additional information which might help him to identify the problem.

Comment: Is your controller method trying to connect to a machine which is not available in your EC2 setup (bad DB hostname, bad queue server hostname etc)? You can add a few log lines in your controller method to find out how far in the code is your request progressing and there by identifying the bottle neck. Since you say the files in the public folder are available, I am assuming port 80 is accessible on your ec2 instance.

Comment: and do I just put this at the beginning of the file?  Something like  logger.debug "I have made it here" Update: It looks like I put it in anywhere in the def...end

Comment: Nothing happens when I put logger.debug "I have made it here" in my controller.  It just searches and searches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I needed to prcompile the assets by doing one of the folling

Adding this to my deploy.rb file

```
after "deploy:restart", "deploy:precompile"

namespace :deploy do

  desc "Compile assets"
  task :precompile, :roles => :app do
    run "cd #{release_path} && rake RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} assets:precompile"
  end

end
```

Running this in the current directory

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
```

Or adding this to the capfile

```
load 'deploy/assets'
```